# concatenating a string onto all elements of [string] haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to haskell and can't seem to figure this out. I've been using the scalpel web scraping tool and want to concatenate a bunch of URL extensions with a URL.

For example, lets say we have scraped some URL extensions into a list of strings

```
result =["/contact","/content"]
```

and we have let

```
websiteURL = "www.website.com"
```

how do I arrive at the list ?

```
["www.website.com/contact", "www.website.com/content"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
map ("aaa"++) ["bbb", "ccc"]
==> [ "aaabbb", "aaaccc" ]
```

Comment: This makes me feel a bit better. I was on the right lines, but had the syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You want to traverse your list of extensions and apply a function to each, so some kind of `map` is required.

The function you want to apply is to append the `websiteURL` string, so the answer is:

```
map (mappend websiteURL) result
```

If you didn't know the `mappend` function, you could find it by searching hoogle for `Monoid a => a -> a -> a`.

(I'll let other people generalize to more abstract types if they want...)

Comment: If you don't know the `mappend` function, how can you possibly be expected to come up with the type signature `Monoid a => a -> a -> a`? And in this case, typing in the natural type signature search of `String -> String -> String` doesn't list the right function until quite late in the list of results.